# Change "OK Google" hotword

Tags: google, search

I want to change the Hotword for the Google Assistant.

Is it possible to change the hotword from "OK Google" to something else?

Do i need a rooted device?

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: According to a comment below, the OpenMic+ app has been taken down by the author.

---

According to Google Help Forums, this feature seems  **not** to have been implemented yet:

> At this moment, changing the **hotword** is not an available feature.
>   However, we appreciate your feedback, and your feature request has
>   been noted.

Fortunately there is a workaround:

There is an application, [Open Mic+ for Google Now](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.RSen.OpenMic.Pheonix&hl=en), with lots of customisation and enables the user to change the hot phrase.

> With Open Mic+ you aren’t limited to “Okay Google”. Live out your
>   sci-fi fantasies, support your favourite team, and just feel awesome
>   with complete control over your phone.

Instructions:

- Download and install the latest version of Google Search App on your device if you haven’t already.
- Download and install Open Mic+ For Google Now App.
- After installation ,open the app Open Mic+ For Google Now.
- As soon as you open up the app you will see a warning indicating you to turn off **Google Now Hot word Detection**, here click on Settings >>Voice >> OK Google Detection >> Turn it Off.
- Now head back to Open Mic+ For Google Now App and tap on Say area with a pencil icon.
- Here type any command with which you want your Google Now respond like “**Hey Device**” and then hit Set.
- Once set click on the Play button.
- That’s it you now have successfully customized and changed Google Now wake up command from OK Google to something else in this case to **Hey Device**.

Hope this helps

References:

1. [Alternative to "Ok Google"](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/googlehome/_NHUA5VGL8w)
2. [How To Change Google Now Command From Ok Google To Something Else](http://www.wtfandroid.com/change-google-now-command-from-ok-google-to-something-else/)

Comment: The Open Mic+ play store page says: "Due to MIT overworking me, this application will no longer be supported by me :( Thank you to everyone for all the support, I hope to get back to this one some day.
"

Comment: Confirmation that the Open Mic+ has been abandoned: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=67254032&postcount=503

Comment: Thanks for the update! But it it still possible to use the last release version?

Comment: It gave me various errors on my Samsung Galaxy Tab S3 http://a.co/bse54JM  (newly purchased).  The main use case for wanting to change this is having multiple Android devices close to you, each of which responding to the same hotword.

Comment: OpenMic+ has been taken down by the author, hence I think this post must be deleted or locked. Why lead people on a wild goose chase